# Make bigger the bounding box of text tag in SVG

Tags: html, svg, filter, text, dropshadow

#### What I've got:

I have got a text inside a svg element, like this:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100%" height="100%">

<filter id="filter" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0">
    <feFlood flood-color="black" result="black"/>
    <feComposite operator="over" in="SourceGraphic" in2="black" result="Ext" />

    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        <feMergeNode in="Ext" />
    </feMerge>
</filter>



<style>
  @font-face {
                font-family: "Misto";
                src: url(data:font/woff2;base64,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);
             }
   .first-part{
       font: 16px Misto;
       font-size: 0.5rem;
       filter:  url('#filter');
       white-space: pre;
       text-align: center;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       fill: #fff;
       display: block;
   }
</style>
<text x="50" y="20" class="first-part"  text-anchor="middle"  
      shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="optimizeLegibility"  
      lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">Do You Think, </text>


</svg>
```

[Click Here](https://codepen.io/James-Mdk-Marc/pen/XWyydJO) to see a live example

#### What I want:

I want to increase the height of the filter effect cause if I try to add a `feDropShadow` to the text, it gets cut, for example on i.

[image: Shadow is cut]

Furthermore, I would like to scale up the text programatically but the size of the filter stays the same and the text gets cut.

How to increase the height of the bbox in proportion of the text?

Comment: increase the size of the filter i.e. set x, y < 0 and width, height > 100%